# Splunk Avg Query

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-formula, splunk-calculation, splunk-dashboard

I am consuming some data using an API, I want to calculate avg time it took for all my customer, after each ingestion (data consumed for a particular customer), I print a time matrix for that customer.

`timechart span=24h avg(total_time)`

Now to calculate average I cannot simply extract the time field and do avg(total_time), because if customerA completes ingestion in 1 hour, and customerB takes 24 hours, customer A will be logged 24 times and B will be logged once, giving me inaccurate results and bringing down the average.

How do I create a filter let's say time duration is 7 days, so I get only those log lines for a particular customer which has the maximum total_time over a period of 7 days. i.e one log line per customer that has max total_time over a period of 7 days for that particular customer.

Comment: | bin _time span=24h
| stats max(total_time) as max_time by _time customer
| timechart span=24h avg(max_time) as average

That's the solution just in case anybody needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

| bin _time span=24h
| stats max(total_time) as max_time by _time customer
| timechart span=24h avg(max_time) as average